# I make people happy yet also let them scream

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

My only friend left me this puzzle when he visited my house for the
first time and I tried to solve it but it's too hard for me. Maybe you can help me out:

> You can find me in every sports team,
>   I make people happy yet also let them scream
>
> I am almost always there, 
> You can find me everywhere
>
> I am the definition of start, 
> But not in a certain Art
>
> This Art doesn't punch you KO, 
> Though has something in common with
>   SO
>
> As a last thing I want to slam, 
> Where I definitely not am:
>
> EnCt2224b070f865c161072137d84694d62182886d2ca224b070f865c161072137d84vBDHbp+d6wH
>   KuVMZw1dbQg0tYvQyIwEmS
>
> Now be advised and hear, 
> I am hidden within pear
>
> I am also used in this text, 
> But in another language indexed
>
> If you manage to encipher.
> it will surely have a hit
>
> My reputation is not high, 
> So I will now say goodbye
>
> *----------------------------------*
>   What am I referring to, LordCanada?
>
> GL with the riddle,
>   *John Johnson*

Hint 1:

> Look at the **exact** formatting of the riddle! Do you see any irregularities?

Hint 2:

> Look closely. There is a URL hidden in the text. (Hint 1 will help you find it)

**MAJOR** Hint 3:

> The Paragraph under the cipher gives you the key.

Hint 4:

> My friend John just texted me that removing "in" will help in finding the key

Hint 5:

> It is intended to first find the key and use it on the cipher text and use the deciphered text to solve the riddle. Use Hint 3 and 4 to get the key.

**MAJORLY MAJOR** Hint 6:

> The decryption key is not a normal word. "in another language indexed" means that the key which is contained as words in the text has to be converted in a certain way before using it as a key

Hint for non-key solving:

> The part under the key isn't helping you with solving in any way. Also my friend is currently in Austria and he sent me another clue: 
> "I am the outcome of good learning,
> but I'm not good at earning."

2. Hint for non-key solving:

   > First of all: the "...slam, where I definetly not am" part is not useful for non-key solving. It's intended to be just a flavortext for adding the encrypted code. Now the hint: I think "SO" could refer to a similar website as you are on right now.

*Feel free to ask a few question about things you don't understand.*

Comment: Hello, welcome on Puzzling ! I have edited your title, feel free to change if it doesn't fit your puzzle. Can you tell what is the purpose of the puzzle ? Find who you are ? Find the meaning of the 2 encrypted lines ? Or may be finding what to do is part of the puzzle (in this case you can use the "enigmatic-puzzle" tag)

Comment: Will think of a better title. Good question on the purpose of the puzzle. It is not really a "Who am I" but almost every line in the puzzle refers to the same certain thing which you have to identify. So kinda "Who am I". I will think of a non-puzzle-breaking change of text to make it more specific

Comment: Well I think it's safe to say it's not "I" because we all know that isn't in team

Comment: How can the hash be a hash? It's 101 bytes long.

Comment: Well, there's only one period in the whole deal, after "encipher".

Comment: @Krii oh sorry, I used the word "hash" because Jynxed used it. But it's just an enciphered text

Comment: @DanRussell correct! Now think of what you can do with that.

Comment: Is your "friend" actually called John Johnson or should we treat the name as a clue?

Comment: The name is only alias like Anon or Anonymous. It has nothing to do with the riddle and was only added for the sentence "What am I referring to, LordCanada?" to make the purpose of the riddle clearer

Comment: Note that despite the comment from Lord of dark above, the ciphertext appears to be one long wrapped line rather than two lines. Its structure is strange and seems best described as follows. "EnCt2" then 64=24+16+24 hex digits of which the first and last blocks are identical, then 32 characters of alphanumeric nonsense. I think the fact that "EnCt2" ends, and the alphanumeric nonsense behind, with a hex digit is just coincidence.

Comment: Perhaps the period is the extension separator in the URL mentioned in hint 2. It's not hard to find an "h", a "t", an "m" and an "l" in that order after it, but I don't see them speaking at regular intervals or at consistent places within lines...

Comment: It also seems highly fishy that the line after the only period begins with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You are close to solving the "first part" of the riddle. Keep the 2 hints in mind and look closer.

Comment: ("Behind" in my previous comment is of course an autocorrect typo for "begins". And "speaking" in the one after it should be "appearing". I should be more careful when using mobile devices...)

Comment: Well, I've found the URL and understand what sort of thing the ciphertext is now, but before that's useful to me there's clearly one more piece of information I need to figure out...

Comment: I have a few ideas floating around but nothing that will stick. Really not sure where to find the encryption password as I've tried pretty much everything I could think of. I'm assuming that is the key to the whole thing.

Comment: It looks to me as if everyone looking at this (it may just be me) is stuck. Specifically, (1) it looks as if progress is impossible without identifying the key with which the blob is encrypted; many kinda-plausible guesses turn out not to work and it's not clear what direction to go in; and (2) without finding out what's inside that encrypted blob the riddle seems hard to get a grip on. (Especially as it's not clear which parts of it are clues to the *answer* and which to the *encryption key*.)

Comment: All of which is a lengthy way of saying that perhaps another hint might be a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I edited hint 3 for you guys.

Comment: Looks like we're still all stuck. (My answer has an incomplete but representative list of things I've tried; am I just thinking about this completely wrong?)

Comment: (I tried removing "in" in various places and unfortunately it didn't help me find the key. No one else seems to have found it either. Looks like your friend John overestimated our collective mental capacities.)

Comment: Just to make it clear. The "in" doesn't have to be a word for itself. Any word can contain "in". Also try to combine hint 3 and 4!

Comment: I was already trying to combine hints 3 and 4, and had been looking for other words containing "in" (notably "within", suggesting e.g. "iampear" and "Iampear" as keys; these, and several other variants, don't appear to work). Hint 5, of course, reveals only what was already obvious -- but I sympathize with your difficulty, because very likely there is no way to hint further at the key that doesn't completely give it away. I'm sorry that I (and anyone else who's attacking this) am being so dim...

Comment: This is driving me crazy for some time.... one more hint pretty please

Comment: also, removing in is "I am hidden with pear" in right direction?

Comment: @smriti yes it is and I will wait some time 'till giving another hint

Comment: "I am also used in this text, But in another language indexed" -> Not sure if this helps, but "Art" is a german word (Die Art). And in the riddle, Art is written uppercase all the time.

Comment: Interesting observation. Neither "art" nor "Art" works as decryption key, though.

Comment: Ahhh... I was sooo looking forward for the hint, but the hint is again for cipher, and the deciphering continues...(I was hoping for the hint for the riddle part)

Comment: If my analysis of the enciphered blob is correct, the plaintext should be 7 characters long.  The message uses 256-bit AES, but due to some poor choices the effective key length is only 64 bits (the key is expanded into a hex string and then truncated to 16 bytes before being encrypted with itself).  Unfortunately the MAC is keyed on the whole password, and the message is too short to decrypt without it.

Comment: Is there any hint to which other language we need to use to convert the key?

Comment: *Majorly Major* $-$ love it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, here's where I am stuck. First of all, the mysterious encrypted blob.

> The unique full stop and following lowercase initial letter suggest the website encipher.it, and a bit of websearching also reveals that the format of the blob matches something they use. Pasting the blob into the obvious place on their website makes the "Encipher it" button turn into "Decipher it" (note: it *doesn't* on my mobile devices) but now we need a key to proceed.

Unfortunately,

> if there's any clear indication of a key in the riddle I have so far failed to notice it. Some things I have tried (getting an "Invalid password" message every time) are: "a" (present in "team", very common letter, featuring in a happy "aaaah" and also in a screaming "aargh", at the start of the alphabet), "LordCanada" for obvious reasons, "password" because why not?, both "space" and " " (there are spaces in "every sports team", even commoner than "a", people need a certain amount of space, "in space no one can hear you scream", you might kinda consider the big bang to have occurred "in space"), "GL" (hidden in plain sight). Maybe (in view of hint 3, which at the time said something like "the stuff before the encrypted blob has nothing to do with the key") it's an error to look in the early portions of the riddle for hints of the key -- I guess they're hints for the actual answer instead -- but the post-blob part gives me no ideas at all.

After the update to hint 3, which makes it clearer where to look for the encryption key (though not altogether clear -- what exactly is a "paragraph" here?), I have ...

> tried all of the following, with no success. "pit", "pip", seed", "pits", "pips", "seeds", and "core" (actual things hidden within a pear). All 10 nonempty substrings of "pear". All 12 things obtained by inserting one of {"i","I","iam","Iam"} somewhere into the middle of "pear". "aria" and "arIa" (an actual word after "I am hidden within ...", though it extends into the next stanza which hint 3 may or may not be intended to exclude). "partridge" ("in a pear tree") and variants "Partridge" and "a partridge". Hundreds of things could in principle be hidden within a pear, a pear tree, or something made of pearwood, but I have only so much patience :-).

I assume I should be focusing on decrypting the blob rather than looking for actual answers as such before doing so. As you might gather from the second spoilered block above, I can think of a few things to do with the pre-blob material (though the business about the Art seems too vague to be useful to me at present) and nothing useful to do with the post-blob material.

> That hear/pear non-rhyme seems like it might be significant, though nothing I can think of to do with it makes perfect sense of it. E.g., perhaps "... and hear" indicates that we should replace "pear" with something that sounds the same ("pare", "pair"). Perhaps the non-rhyme indicates that "pear" is an error and needs to be replaced with something similar that does rhyme with "hear" ("peer", perhaps). These things all seem harder to find something useful hidden inside than "pear".

Comment: Wow I'm so freaking impressed. This is my first puzzle and I wouldn't have thought that one can think of so many different ways to approach my puzzle. I want to give you one hint. Don't think too complex. It's my first puzzle after all. Oh and the part of the riddle you are talking about in your 3rd spoiler is a very valuable one.

Comment: Using the "hear" hint and the spelling of the non-rhyme, perhaps hidden within the non-rhyming word is an organ used for hearing? Or maybe not. This does not seem to square with later hints.

Comment: There is, but it's one of the many kinda-plausible possibilities that gets only an "Invalid password" message from the decryption tool. And it doesn't fit the very recent hint that the key is "not a normal word".

Comment: That particular segment of the riddle made me think of HTML. It's just how "hear", "pear" and "text" appeared so close together (hypertext?) and "language" so close behind. Not sure if this helps though.

Answer (score 1):

That's the best I can come up with:

> A Starter? 
>
>  The first person to make a play in a team is a starter
>
>  You can start with anything anywhere
>
>  It is "start" and has "Art" in it
>
>  It's not a martial art, but you start a family with your significant other
>
>  The following thing after "where I definately not am" appears to be a hash cypher, which would need a starter value to encode
>
>  A seed is the starter of a plant,
>
>  A starter again, referring to the hash
>
>  "If you manage to encipher" is a hint as to the string of numbers and letters being a hash,
>
>  Someone newly starting something, a starter, would not have a high reputation in that task.

Comment: Please explain each line why you think the answer is a starter.

Comment: fixed. Sorry, new here.

Comment: Wow incredible answer @Jynxed! It isn't the searched answer though. You missed two valuable points: First explain what "I make people happy yet also let them scream" has to do with starter and secondly the hash should be used to solve the riddle

Comment: Please spoiler your answer so that other readers won't accidentally have the puzzle ruined before they can respond to it.

Answer (score 1):

Edited the previous answer(Again)

my last guess was

> talent

Then it was

> star

After the new hint, I came up with bunch of answers, and now I am super confused,
 anyways I am updating the answer

**My new guess is**

> legend ([meanings](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=legend%20meaning))

You can find me in every sports team,

> every sports has legend/icon/star/title

I make people happy yet also let them scream

> happy : legend of tarzan 
>  scream : [urban legends](http://urbanlegends.about.com/od/horrors/)

I am almost always there,
You can find me everywhere

> have a look at your desktop screen (icons)

I am the definition of start,
But not in a certain Art
This Art doesn't punch you KO,
Though has something in common with SO

> still no idea about this 
> (I am taking SO as "Stack overflow")
> So, icon of both sites or stack overflow legendary badge

As a last thing I want to slam,
Where I definitely not am:

> Thank god this is not a part of riddle, frankly I was tired of referencing door(Slam! glad that door was closed)

Comment: Great guess again @smriti. But as you said there are still a few points unclear. The meaning of your word is close to the thought one again but the word itself is far away from it.

Comment: @LordCanada Ahh...Dammit, Oh well, I hope the Third time's the charm

Comment: Just want to point out again that your last guess was almost correct!

Comment: @LordCanada I dont think this is an answer, but is it "goal"?

Comment: Nope it isn't even close.

Comment: @LordCanada just one more smaaaal question, is it related to (rot13  ubebfpbcr)

Comment: Not exactly but in a certain way.

Comment: @LordCanada ahh, hell with it, I am trying again(long-shot again) I updated this answer, check it out now

Comment: 1. You forgot to include my last hint. 2. Still very close but not the answer. 3. I will add a new hint shortly. 4. Keep it up man! I really love your answers!

Comment: @LordCanada >_<  thanks for your feedback, I am reaaaly looking forward to new hint, by any chance is this answer doesn't describe person at all?

Comment: @LordCanada I have updated yet again, have a look at it.

Comment: Only right guess in your new answer was what SO means :P. Since you are struggling with that part I will give a secret personal hint: Think of what SO is about. In SOs "topic" there is something that has a different definition of start than the "normal" world. *I hope I didn't give away too much with this hint :-/*

Comment: @LordCanada Ahh.. its about the nobel art of programming! you can relax, I am VERY weak at that :(

Comment: @LordCanada after THIS many days, all I got is "return 0"

Comment: ok I'll give you a hint since you are that weak with programming. It has to with a datatype.

Comment: @LordCanada is it p...p....pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, just maybe another observation that might lead to the answer:

> I am also used in this text, 
> But in another language indexed

It could follow that this is referring to:

> Indexed Languages and Indexed grammers as seen here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_language

So maybe...

> one piece of the poem, which is in an Indexed Language, is the decryption key?

Answer (score 0):

This riddle is driving me crazy for some time, and yesterday, I am going through some good old riddles, and this struck me(I was gonna wait till the next hint, but I cant anymore)

Is it

> Ace

You can find me in every sports team,

> Every sports team has ace player

I make people happy yet also let them scream

> Why 'S' is scary? Because it makes cream 'scream'(this is how I got the idea for answer)

I am almost always there,
You can find me everywhere

> letter 's' is used oftentimes in words

I am the definition of start,

> 's' starting start(yea, I am not sure about this)

or

> in cards it can go like : ace,two,three...

But not in a certain Art
This Art doesn't punch you KO,
Though has something in common with SO

> This can be related to tennis and similar games : a service that an opponent is unable to return and thus wins a point.

As a last thing I want to slam,

> Door?

Where I definitely not am

> Door does not contain letter s

I am stuck on the second part! Any thoughts on this answer

Comment: Very good answer man. It's not correct though :-/. The answer is not correct and therefore the guesses are also not but the word is very close to the solution. I wonder if u can solve the riddle without using the code...

Comment: @LordCanada hmm.. I thought this was it... -_- , Oh well, thinking CAPS on again!!